# Segmentation fault - Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I am getting a "segmentation fault" error when I am starting virtualbox in RHEL 5.6. I can delete the older version and install a newer one. However, I am trying to reproduce the error in my test bed. I googled it but I did not find anything related to the exact cause of this error.

Comment: I checked in the affected machine that we are not having a folder VirtualBoxVMs. I deleted the VirtualboxVMs in the testbed to replicate the error. However, I am still able to open the Virtualbox application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged in as root and restarted the vboxdrv kernel module using the command /etc/init.d/vboxc. Now it is working fine without the segmentation fault error.